# What does Gradle 'build' task include exactly

Tags: java, gradle

I have searched on Gradle docs and on the stackoverflow and some other places but I can't find information about what is bundled in this task in depth, or I missed it, if so please point me to the direction.

- It comes from `java-base` plugin, right?
- Running `gradle -q tasks` doesn't say much about it.

> build - Assembles and tests this project.

- Running `gradle help --task build` shows detailed info, ok - but it show where the task is used, in which groups is included, type of a task, and paths.
- I have tried to track manually what does comes with it, and noticed, compile, test etc tasks.

I would like to know what exactly comes from Gradle build task, what are the task dependencies.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [Gradle Task Tree Plugin](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) to see the task dependencies

eg:

```
plugins {
    id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.3.1"
}
```

Then run

```
gradle build taskTree
```

Output

```
:build
+--- :assemble
|    \--- :jar
|         \--- :classes
|              +--- :compileJava
|              \--- :processResources
\--- :check
     \--- :test
          +--- :classes
          |    +--- :compileJava
          |    \--- :processResources
          \--- :testClasses
               +--- :compileTestJava
               |    \--- :classes
               |         +--- :compileJava
               |         \--- :processResources
               \--- :processTestResources
```

Comment: Up that plugin version to `1.3.1` if you want to fix the decorater error message as discussed [here](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree/issues/32). Prefer this answer since it gives something reusable as well as an answer :)

Comment: This gives a great insight of the dependencies

Answer (score 21):

From the Gradle Java plugin [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html)

[image: build dependencies]

It's dependencies are the check & assemble task which you can see have their own dependencies

Answer (score 15):

Starting with [version 4.0](https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/console.html#sec:console_build_output) you have to run `gradle build --console=plain` to see the complete list of task dependencies.

If you use `java-base` plugin then the dependencies are:

```
$ gradle build --console=plain
:assemble
:check
:build
```

[image]

If you use `java` (which [automatically applies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/standard_plugins.html#sec:language_plugins) `java-base`) then the dependencies are:

```
$ gradle build --console=plain
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources
:testClasses
:test
:check
:build
```

[image]

In order to see the exact chain of dependencies shown in the pictures above I used a little Perl helper that can be run inside of a Gradle project. It produces a [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) string describing dependency graph:

```
#/bin/perl
use strict;

my @deps;
my %tasks;

getDeps($ARGV[0]);
printDot();

sub getDeps {
    my $task = shift;
    $tasks{$task} = "";
    chomp(my @subtasks = `gradle $task`);
    @subtasks = grep { $_ =~ "^:" } @subtasks;
    pop @subtasks;
    foreach(@subtasks) {
        my ($s) = $_ =~ "^:(.*) ";
        push @deps, "$task -> $s;";
        if(!defined $tasks{$s}) {getDeps($s)}
    }
}

sub printDot {
    my $dot = "digraph main {\n";
    if(@deps>1) {
        foreach(@deps) {$dot .= "$_\n"}
    } else {
        $dot .= "$ARGV[0];\n";
    }
    print $dot . "}";
}
```

Then run the following to turn the output into a PNG image:

```
$ t=build; perl dependencies.pl $t | tred | dot -T png > $t.png
```

or ASCII text:

```
$ t=build; perl dependencies.pl $t | tred | graph-easy > $t.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply

Comment: I recommend `gradle build --dry-run` over `gradle build --console=plain`, since the dry run is designed to print the tasks that would have been output rather than actually running the tasks. ([`--dry-run` documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_execution_options))

Answer (score 1):

#### In short:

Compiles, tests and assembles the code into a JAR file

#### More info [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/):

> You’ll use the gradle build task frequently. This task compiles,
> tests, and assembles the code into a JAR file. You can run it like
> this:
>
> gradle build
>
> After a few seconds, "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" indicates that the build has
> completed.
>
> To see the results of the build effort, take a look in the build
> folder. Therein you’ll find several directories, including these three
> notable folders:
>
> - classes. The project’s compiled .class files.
> - reports. Reports produced by the build (such as test reports).
> - libs. Assembled project libraries (usually JAR and/or WAR files).

#### Gradle Tasks view of Eclipse / Spring Tool Suite

[image]

#### Sample dry-run:

`gradlew build --dry-run`
`gradlew -m build` (Same as above)

> :compileJava SKIPPED
>  :processResources SKIPPED
>  :classes
> SKIPPED
>  :bootWarMainClassName SKIPPED
>  :bootWar SKIPPED
> :bootStartScripts SKIPPED
>  :bootDistTar SKIPPED
>  :bootDistZip
> SKIPPED
>  :jar SKIPPED
>  :startScripts SKIPPED
>  :distTar
> SKIPPED
>  :distZip SKIPPED
>  :war SKIPPED
>  :assemble
> SKIPPED
>  :compileTestJava SKIPPED
>  :processTestResources
> SKIPPED
>  :testClasses SKIPPED
>  :test SKIPPED
>  :check
> SKIPPED
>  :build SKIPPED
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 32s